# Add a line to a boxplot using plotly

Tags: r, plotly

Is it possible to add vertical line to a boxplot in plotly? I know it works in `ggplot2`, but I need it in plotly. Would be nice if I don't need to convert my static ggplot every time.

Here is a minimal example

```
plot_ly(x = ~rnorm(50), type = "box") %>% 
   add_trace(x = ~c(0.75),y=c(-2,0.5),type='scatter',mode='lines')
```

Instead of the line stoping before I want the line to go through the boxplot. In addition I want the same plot extent as the single boxplot.

Comment: I tried setting a value for the y-axis of the box-plot, but then my boxplot didnt appear anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the sequence of calls:

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(x = ~c(0.75), y=c(-2,2), type='scatter', mode='lines') %>% 
  add_boxplot(x = ~rnorm(50), inherit = F) %>% 
  layout(yaxis = list(range = c(-2, 2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was already trying to build my own boxplots in plotly. That makes it a lot easier. Didn't think of switching the order, coding with lack of sleep is just more buggy, I guess.